# Accessory Tapped not firing segue in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with static cells.  I am using the cellForRowAtIndexPath: to create my cells.  One of them has an disclosure accessory indicator added to it programmatically.  And its respective method is like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     NSLog(@"aBTFRAIP:accessory tapped");
}
```

However there is no log in the console.  When I tap the cell, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method fires for that cell.  How can I fix this?

Comment: You should probably be using dynamic cells if you're adding cells to your table. When you use static cells, you're not supposed to implement any of the data source methods.

Comment: ok but if i wanted to add images to uiimageviews of each cell programmatically, based on their index row, how could I do that without the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: With static cells, you should have IBOutlets to each cell (or directly to the subviews if you want), and update them using the outlet.

Answer (score 2):

The `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method works for the detail-disclosure button (the blue one) and only when the button itself is tapped on, as opposed to tapping on the cell.

If you tap the cell `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will get fired and **not** `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` like you want.